# Pycharm Couldn't refresh skeletons for remote interpreter

Tags: pycharm, docker-compose

I've set a docker-compose as my python interpreter for my Django application, the first time everything worked as expected, however when I add a new requirement in `requirements.txt` something goes wrong, first I got a message stating that the requirement was successfully installed and then get this message

```
Couldn't refresh skeletons for remote interpreter
            com.github.dockerjava.api.exception.NotModifiedException: 
            caused by:
com.github.dockerjava.api.exception.NotModifiedException:
```

After that I keep seeing the warning telling me that the requirement has not been satisfied.

My Docker daemon configuration is set to:
[image]

And my docker-compose interpreter looks like:
[image]
The only way it seems to work is by:

1. run in the terminal `docker-compose build`
2. removing the container and creating it again with the ide Run button.

In my opinion these are not good solutions and I think it should work directly from the IDE, so is there any extra configuration that needs to be performed for it to work properly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently this was an issue on version 2018.1.1 and has been fixed in version 2018.1.2, for future reference [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues) is a list of tickets issues and with detailed information and what they are doing to fix the issues, I think you need to sign up, but it's free anyway.

Answer (score 6):

Related error (maybe - got here searching for mine, so others may too), but for other reasons.

The error was:

```
Couldn't refresh skeletons for remote interpreter 
Failed to change an owner of the skeletons volume: 
Failed to change permissions for the skeletons volumeRegenerate skeletons
```

If you're checking this question in 2021, check the resolution for the [PY-49305 issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-49305).

In summary, disable Docker Compose V2:

[image: Docker Compose V2 option in Docker Windows]

Comment: This work for me in PyCharm 2021.3.2 (Professional Edition) and Docker Dashboard 4.4.2 in a M1 Monterey 12.2 (21D49).

Answer (score 4):

[image]

If you're still seeing this in PyCharm `2020.2` then do this:

- close PyCharm
- run this in a terminal

```
docker ps -a | grep -i pycharm | awk '{print $1}' | xargs docker rm
```

- launch PyCharm again